# Firebase import error: '__spreadArray' is not exported from 'tslib'

Tags: reactjs, firebase

How can I solve this problem?

> ./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/esm5/prebuilt-306f43d8-45d6f0b9.js
> Attempted import error: '__spreadArray' is not exported from 'tslib'
> (imported as 'e').

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you had any chance to solve this?